# Form validation error not showing up in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was creating a form to register users, I added the validation error to check if the email already exists in the database. However, when you feed in an email which is already in the database, the form doesn't show up the error, it just resets.

forms.py:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    institute = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Making name required
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'institute' )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError("Cannot use this email. It's already registered")
        return email
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
        user.profile.institute = form.cleaned_data.get('institute')
        print(user.profile.institute)
        user.save()
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return render(request,'home.html')

form = SignUpForm()
context = {
    'form' : form,
}

return render(request,'register.html', context)
```

I am using crispy forms

Comment: Does it work with the answer below?

Comment: yes, the answer solves the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For a validation error to show up you need to put the same form again into the `context` dictionary.**

In your particular example, if the form is not valid, the outer `if`-statement ends and a new form is creates with `form= SignUpForm()` and added to the rendered context. As a consequence, the above code simply returns a new empty form to the context, if the returned form is not valid.

Adapt your code, so to pass the invalid form to the response. Then you will see the error:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db() # load the profile instance created by the signal
        user.profile.institute = form.cleaned_data.get('institute')
        print(user.profile.institute)     
        user.save() 
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1') 
        user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user) 
        return render(request,'home.html')
    else:  # if the form is not valid, pass the invalid form in the context
        return render(request,'register.html', { 'form' : form, })
form = SignUpForm() 
context = { 'form' : form, }
return render(request,'register.html', context
```